# Can't figure out a one-to-many bidirectional association with join table

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, join

I'm trying to figure out this mapping, and somehow it's just eluding me. It's irritating, because it seems like it should be a common case.

I have a basic Parent and Child class with a join table between them. The Child class is dependent on the Parent: if an Child is removed from the Parent, the Child ought to be deleted as well. The Hibernate docs say that this works by specifying cascade="all,delete-orphan".

But the schema won't allow it. If I use a < one-to-many >, I can't specify a column and the join won't work. If I use a < many-to-many unique="true" > per the Hibernate docs, I can't specify a cascade.

Here's what I have now, taken from the [Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en-US/html_single/#assoc-bidirectional-join-12m):

```
<class name="Parent" table="parent_table">
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="string"/>
    <list table="my_join_table" name="children">
        <key column="parent_id"/>
        <list-index column="idx">
        <!-- how do I put a cascade on this!? -->
        <many-to-many column="child_id" 
                      class="Child"
                      unique="true"/>
    </list>
</class>

<class name="Child" table="child_table">
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="string"/>
    <join table="my_join_table" inverse="true" optional="false">
        <key column="child_id"/>
        <many-to-one name="parent" column="parent_id" not-null="true"/>
    </join>
</class>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out myself, finally.

The cascade attribute needs to go on the list element rather than the many-to-many:

```
 <list table="my_join_table" name="children" cascade="all,delete-orphan">
    <key column="parent_id"/>
    <list-index column="idx">
    <!-- how do I put a cascade on this!? -->
    <many-to-many column="child_id" 
                  class="Child"
                  unique="true"/>
</list>
```